# Module firebase not found in script

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, google-analytics

I try to do something simple, import firebase in my index.html and start analytics.

I import the code, but i have `ReferenceError: firebase is not defined`. Please what is wrong with my code ?

```
<body>

<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/10.7.1/firebase-app.js"></script>
<script  src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/10.7.1/firebase-analytics.js"></script>

<script>
  // Initialize Firebase with your configuration
  const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "AIzaSyDMOXXXXXXXXXXXu6fMbeqU",
    authDomain: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXe.firebaseapp.com",
    projectId: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
    storageBucket: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX3370",
    appId: "1:XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX:web:XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
    measurementId: "G-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
  };

  // Initialize Firebase
  firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

  // Initialize Firebase Analytics
  const analytics = firebase.analytics();

  // Log an event (optional)
  analytics.logEvent('star_html5_game');

  // You can start tracking events and user interactions here
</script>


</body>
```

Now I try this, no error, but nothing happened in the console of firebase

```
<script type="module">
  // Import the functions you need from the SDKs you need
  import { initializeApp } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/10.7.1/firebase-app.js";
  import { getAnalytics } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/10.7.1/firebase-analytics.js";
  // TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
  // https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries

  // Your web app's Firebase configuration
  // For Firebase JS SDK v7.20.0 and later, measurementId is optional
  const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "AIzaSyDMO-QXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXeqU",
    authDomain: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXfirebaseapp.com",
    projectId: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
    storageBucket: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
    appId: "1:XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXb63",
    measurementId: "G-25L48DR5H1"
  };

  // Initialize Firebase
  const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
  const analytics = getAnalytics(app);
</script>
```

I finally use this code, no error, event not found in the console, I don't have the realtime user poping up in the realtime analytics in firebase.

```
  // Import the functions you need from the SDKs you need
  import { initializeApp } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/10.7.1/firebase-app.js";
  import { getAnalytics, logEvent } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/10.7.1/firebase-analytics.js";
  // TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
  // https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries

  // Your web app's Firebase configuration
  // For Firebase JS SDK v7.20.0 and later, measurementId is optional
  const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "AIzaSyDMO-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
    authDomain: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.com",
    projectId: "gXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
    storageBucket: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXX.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
    appId: "1:3XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX1b63",
    measurementId: "G-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
  };

  // Initialize Firebase
  const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
  const analytics = getAnalytics(app);
  
  logEvent(analytics ,'test_event_from_game', { name: 'hiiiiiiiiiii'});
    
  console.log(app);
  console.log(analytics);
```

Comment: What are you expecting to happen differently in the console other than what you observe? The code you have doesn't really *do* anything worth logging.

Comment: @DougStevenson this code should initialize analytics and automatically firebase should detect new user, but it is not working. Even when i try to log, i have an error `ReferenceError: firebase is not defined`

Answer (score -1):

`firebase` is not found because the version of the API you are using leverages the "modular API" syntax and not the (older, should not be used if possible) "namespaced API".

Under "namespaced API" (v8 and below) you would import `firebase` and then leverage the entire library using `firebase.initializeApp()` and `firebase.analytics()`, etc...

But the newer (better) "modular API" is more function oriented.  Your second code snippet is appropriate for the "modular API".

As @Doug points out in his comment, the code you are showing us in your second example really doesn't accomplish anything.  It initializes the client to communicate with our Firebase project (`app = initializeApp(....)`) and it gets a handle to the analytics service (`analytics = getAnalytics(app)`)....but that's it.  Your code does not show that anything is actually used beyond that.  None of the code you are showing would actually communicate to the Firebase server in any way.  It sets your client (your "app") up so that it is ***ready*** to use the Firebase services, but it doesn't actually invoke anything.

Comment: Hello @Greg, by default, when I initialize firebase in others project, just after initialization, firebase analytics starts collecting data for example user using the app and localization in realtime. Why it is not working as expected in this case ? I also add an event, `logEvent(analytics ,'test_event_from_game', { name: 'hiiiiiiiiiii'});`  this event is not in the console.

Comment: Are there any errors/messages in your browser's JS Console (in the Developer Tools) ?

Comment: no error...the link is even here: https://d333wz42ngbii5.cloudfront.net/1/html5-data/html5/html5-1695526988621/build/Build/index.html  you will see 0 error in the console.

Comment: And you are saying that no hits are getting to your Analytics view?

Comment: Yes, not hits. Nothing. I checked in Bigquery, the event is there `SELECT *  FROM `XXXXXXX.analytics_291813849.events_20231227` where event_name = 'test_event_from_game';`  but I can't find the same event in firebase. How is it possible ? and in the data origin is `firebase` and the device is `Android Webview`. Which means accessing directly from link is not triggering the data.

Comment: Are you sure that your integration to BigQuery is set up correctly?  Have you tried looking at the Analytics data from the Firebase Console reports? https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/reports#view-reports

Comment: Yes, everyhing is fine with Bigquery because i can get the others data from the Android App. I just search and don't even find the web data...The firebase project is the same for both Android and Web, only integration is different.

Comment: Where did you get the `firebaseConfig` values from?  Are you using a "web app" or did you use the same values from your "Android app" ?

Comment: they are from Firebase. On each app (Android and Web) I have the config suggested by Firebase. Both are different, I have checked it multiple time. I open a case to Firebase time with screenshots. It is very strange.